# Travis Ci build failed for a java maven project

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I'm using Travic CI as a tool for coutinuous integration on a java maven project and my .travis.yml file is configured this way :

```
language: java
sudo: false
script: mvn clean verify
```

But when I execute, I get this error :

```
The travis ci build could not complete due to an error
The command "eval mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed.
```

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: The above is not your .travis.yml file cause the error message implies you have something like `install: ...` which you didn't show. Furthermore a link to your project would be helpful

Comment: Where is this command beaing called? Could you post all travis file?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are using maven-compiler-plugin 1.8 in you pom.xml. The supported version of travis-ci server is 7, so change it to 1.7
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMW2L.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem !